# Do you know how to show only once the "Download certificate link"?

Tags: laravel

I have a page that lists all registrations (past and next registrations) of a user in conferences. And if there is a certificate available associated with the registration type(s) of the user registration I show a link "Download certificate". So I have the foreach below.

The issue is that when there are more than 1 participant associated with a registration, for example if a registration has 2 participants, and the first participant is associated with a registration type that has a certificate associated with it and the column "certificate_available" as "Y" and the second participant is also associated with a registration type that has a certificate associated with it and the column "certificate_available" as "Y", the "Download certificate" link appears twice for this same registration but the link should only appear once and then when the user clicks in the button the pdf should contain the information about both certificates. But the link should appear only once.

Do you know how to show only once the "Download certificate link"?

```
@foreach($pastRegistrations as $pastRegistration)
    @foreach($pastRegistration->participants as $participant)
        @if ($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y')
            <a href="{{route('conferences.certificateInfo',
           ['regID'=> $pastRegistration->id])}}"
           class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Download certificate</a>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@foreach($pastRegistrations as $pastRegistration)
    @foreach($pastRegistration->participants as $k => $participant)
        <?php 
            $temp = $participant->id;
        ?>
        @if (($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y' && $temp != $participant->id) || $k == 0)
            <a href="{{route('conferences.certificateInfo',
           ['regID'=> $pastRegistration->id])}}"
           class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Download certificate</a>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

You can use a temporary variable to store pastRegistration id and compare it with current loop pastRegistration id to avoid duplicates.
Let me know if you see any error.

Comment: Thanks, dont shows any error but also dont works, It still appears two links when the registration has 2 participants.

Comment: pls try updated answer. I assumed that `participant` has an `id`.

Comment: Thanks, but the syntax like "    @foreach($pastRegistration->participants $k => as $participant)" shows an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$k'".

Comment: oh ok. It should be `as $k => $participant`

Comment: Thanks, but is not working properly. The link "Download certificate" dont appears twice but it appears two list items for the registrations that have 2 participants. Do you know how to solve that?